# Regex function to parse hostname and port

Tags: regex

I have two different strings one is server name,port number other one is the combination of cluster and node name , port number, i want to parse the server name/cluster name and port number from the below strings using regex
Here is the example. Please help me

Hostname1,5500
Hostname1\host,1444

Comment: At the very least try something.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
See also: [ask]

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following pattern:

```
(\w+),(\d+)
```

The hostname match will be **group 1** and the port match will be **group 2**.

I created a regex test page for you to continue testing with other example strings.
https://regex101.com/r/0DlqjJ/1